# How to pass this one component id value into the other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want to pass this SupplierItemModal.jsx component (id) value into the  CreateSupplierItemModal.jsx componet**

[image]

Comment: Where are you including `CreateSupplierItemModal` ? Can you post that code

Comment: Trying adding more description to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the `CreateSupplierItemsModal` is a child to the `SupplierItems` component then you can pass it as a prop. [components and props in reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Else you can create a global state with the context api in reactjs [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: can you show me the code

Answer (score 0):

These are ways you can use:

- If the component is its child you can pass it as [props](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component)
- If their parent is similar you can use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook
- If they are in different paths you can use [redux](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
// Parent Component
<Parent>
  {/* pass function as prop to child */}
  <Child onUpdate={(id) => {
    console.log(id);
  }} />
</Parent>
```

```
// Child Component
function Child({onUpdate}) {

  const handleUpdate = () => {
     onUpdate(id); // invoke function and pass value 
  }

// ...

}
```